# How to import sample schemas to oracle database in docker container through SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle-sqldeveloper

My system is MAC .I don't have oracle database installed in my system .I have oracle database running in docker container in my system .I have SQL Developer installed and I can connect to the database though it . How would I import oracle sample schemas in the database through SQL Developer.i have sample schemas "source code (tar.gz)"downloaded from the below link

https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/releases

Answer (score 2):

Read the readme in the Zip

[image]

If you want to use SQL Developer and it's GUI, pick a schema in the archive, like Human Resources (HR), and use the .sql files.

Open the hr_main.sql file, set your editor to an Administrator level user, and run the the script in a SQL Worksheet using the F5 (execute as script) button.

[image]

You'll have some questions to answer.

Comment: Some of the larger schemas have the data setup to be installed via sqlldr or External Tables so you'll also need an Oracle Client AND access to the database server to create a Directory and load up the files.